# Virus notification which seems like a scam, plus unauthenticated sources script message

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting the icon that means, "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources" no matter what page I am on in Chrome. For example, even in just the Google search page I have that icon. I have also been misdirected very often lately to a screen that starts beeping out loud like an emergency notification and tells me that I have a virus and I should call a certain number etc and that I should not shut off my computer or it will not work etc. (with an actual voice recording that comes on).  I have MacAfee through my internet provider and scans show no problems. How do I fix all this. I am not a computer expert.

Comment: Take it to a shop that specializes in solving your problem. There is a great deal of knowledge necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You update your AV software, you get and run Antimalware software (like Malwarebytes).  You possibly have "PUP" (potentially unwanted software) which is, strictly speaking not a Virus and won't be picked up by AV Software.

You should also  check if this happens when other devices connect though your router and if it occurs when you connect your computer through other routers.   If it occurs only on your network your router may be compromised - in which case complain to whoever provided it to you.